# Bootstrap Carousel auto start pause

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

--UPDATE--
I found the solution, pause didn't work for me, but I found out that if you add:
interval: false
it works just like I wanted to. thank you guys :)

I'm using Bootstrap's 3 carousel, I've been trying to stop it so that it doesn't auto slide. I've been using the function provided by them.
This is what I have:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  .carousel('pause')
})
```

How can I stop it?

This is the HTML, default from Bootstrap's sample page:

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <iframe width="100%" height="630" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9vTguAVhjBo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <iframe width="100%" height="630" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gyV2CSqJi1I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <iframe width="100%" height="630" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/kYbvYS65iDs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, use this line

```
$('.carousel').carousel('pause');
```

Comment: That didn't stop it :(

Comment: Can you show me the HTML? Does your carousel have the carousel class?

Answer (score 2):

> **interval**:The amount of time to delay between automatically cycling an
>   item. If false, carousel will not automatically cycle.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

pass attr data-interval

replace

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

to

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
```

diff : data-interval="false"